# is there any alternative to send_keys() for input text field in python-selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to send data to a text field in html page using selenium python .Is there any method **other than send_keys()** using **python-selenium**?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `send_keys()`?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Windows, you can try using [Pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io/) which uses Microsoft's UIAutomation and has access to sending keys to windows and dialogs, e.g.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('j_username')
elem.clear()
app = Application.Application()
app.window_(title_re='*.Firefox.*').TypeKeys('username')
```